# Get percentage change between two adjacent rows Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have collection with data like that:

```
[
 {'value' => 10},
 {'value' => 11},
 {'value' => 12},
 {'value' => 11.3},
  ....
 {'value' => 16}
]
```

I want to return percentage change between two adjacent rows to become like that. Can you suggest me how to do.

```
 [
     {'value' => 10, 'changed': -9.1},
     {'value' => 11, 'changed': -9.4},
     {'value' => 12, 'changed': 6.19},
     {'value' => 11.3, 'changed': -29.4},
     ....
     {'value' => 16, 'changed': 0} (for last row)
    ]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what have you tried ? did you encounter any issues in your tries ? please read the [ask] guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve that with `map()`

```php
$collection = $collection->map(function ($item, $index) {
    $percentage = $collection->get($index + 1)
        ? number_format(100 * $item['value'] / $collection->get($index + 1)['value'], 2).' %'
        : '0 %';

    return [
        'value' => $item['value'],
        'changed' => $percentage,
    ];
});
```